# Ionic / Cordova - How to set the 'Requires Android' version in Play Store?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, version

How to set the `Requires Android` version in Play Store? It is always 4.4 for all Ionic / Cordova Android Apps. (See Play Store app details)

[image: Screenshot]

The preference `android-minSdkVersion` in `config.xml` is set to 22 (Android 5.1). Also `android-targetSdkVersion` has no effect. And I found nothing in the developer section of Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova does not use/respect the `minSdkVersion` of the `config.xml` correctly.

Workaround:
Go to the directory `platforms/android` and replace the `defaultMinSdkVersion` property value of `build.gradle`. That's it.

The platforms directory is untracked by default (gitignore). It's recommended. No problem. You can replace this value by a build / task tool e.g. Jenkins. Or just place an additional gradle file `build-extras.gradle` into this folder to overwrite some values.

## Update

Cordova Android 8.0.0 fixed this issue. Now `minSdkVersion` of config.xml is respected. See [Release Notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/96975504885a8cf98e251c37b64921337f32c194#diff-c162d66bb4a22683316f0fc47e104078R25)